# High current, low activation voltage relay or analog switch IC

Tags: relay, components, analog-switch

I am working on a gauss rifle, which will be controlled by a computer system running at 1 amp / 5 volts. This computer system will need to interface with the magnetic coils of the rifle in order to control if they are off or on. However, the magnetic coils will (hopefully) be powered by a separate power supply, and will run at a much higher current than the computer system (most likely above 20 amps).

I am looking for some sort of analog switch IC or relay which will allow for the computer system to switch on/off the magnetic coils using 5~ volt signals without being connected to the same power circuit, in order to protect the computer. I would prefer an IC, as the switching will have to occur quickly, and the component must not latch. I am also fine with SMD, but I would prefer through-the-hole components.

I am having trouble finding a component which will satisfy these needs, does anyone know of one? Or should I just use one power supply and just lower the voltage/current going to the computer system? Thank you.

Comment: Inductance of the coil needs to be known. DC resistance of the coil also. How long will the coil be activated for? How quickly do you need the coil current to decay back to zero when deactivated. What voltage and current limit is the power source. What repetition rate are you considering? The devil is in the detail. Consider using a MOSFET connected to the computer by an opto-isolator.

Comment: What is the voltage for the coils? It is usually quite high.